Who owns a gmail account set up in the name of an association by a board member that retired?
The account holds information pertinent to the association and the former board member is claiming ownership as "her personal gmail account".

I'm assuming this is for an HOA. Usually HOA boards have a solicitor who should be providing you legal guidance for this situation.

Details will vary between jurisdictions, of course. Some relevant viewpoints:

Who authorized the creation of an account under that name?
If there was a decision by the board, it would belong to the association. If not, it becomes the question why the association tolerated the use of their name by an individual.
Is the name of the email clearly tied to the association?
If so, the use might touch cybersquatting rules, which are different from country to country.
Is the dispute about past data or the future use of the account?
With some effort, it is possible to scrape much data from the account. A more digitally skilled member of the board might offer to help the retired account administrator.

